# How to take default value in Reactive Form

Tags: html, angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, default-value

I want to Pass default value from HTML to Type script using reactive Form

```
<ul class="list list_2">
<li>Subtotal <span>{{cartTotal | currency:'INR':true:'2.0'}}</span></li>
<li>Shipping Charge<span>{{shipping | currency:'INR':true:'2.0'}}</span></li>
<li>Total <span><input type="text" value="{{cartTotal+shipping | currency:'INR':true:'2.0'}}" class="total" formControlName="TotalAmount" readonly></span></li>
</ul>
```

This is my HTML where i have given default value in input

```
get TotalAmount(){
    return this.billingForm.get("TotalAmount.value")
```

In type script i have this method for getting data and i am using Formgroup

```
billingForm=new FormGroup({
    Address:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    City:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    State:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    Postcode:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    TotalAmount:new FormControl(''),
    PayType:new FormControl('')
  })
```

I want to pass that default value but it always giving null

Comment: Shouldn't this `return this.billingForm.get("TotalAmount.value")` be `return this.billingForm.get("TotalAmount").value`?

Comment: Tried ```this.billingForm.get("TotalAmount").value``` still same giving null value

Comment: ```this.billingForm.controls.get("TotalAmount").value```This expression is not callable.
  Type 'AbstractControl' has no call signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap things differently.

**First**, change your form's initialization.

Add `FormBuilder` as a dependency to your component's consctructor.

```
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {}
```

And use the builder to initialize your form.

```
    this.billingForm = this.builder.group({
      Address: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      City: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      State: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      Postcode: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      TotalAmount: new FormControl(""),
      PayType: new FormControl("")
    });
```

**Then**, your `TotalAmount`'s HTML as:

```
<li>Total <span><input type="text" value="{{TotalAmount | currency:'INR':true:'2.0'}}" class="total" formControlName="TotalAmount" readonly></span></li>
```

So, when you are getting `cartTotal` from your db. Assign `cartTotal+shipping` to your `TotalAmount` FormControl. Like:

```
this.billingForm.get("TotalAmount").setValue(this.cartTotal + this.shipping);
```

**And**, change your `TotalAmount` property as:

```
   get TotalAmount() {
      return this.billingForm.get("TotalAmount").value;
   }
```

**Sample:**

[image]

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkphkn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. You have to access to the form control in order to return the value.

```
return this.billingForm.controls['TotalAmount'].value;
```

Comment: Tried this still giving me blank

Comment: But why do you want to have the total amount as an input on the html? It's not easier to have just a single variable? You can just have <span>{{cartTotal+shipping | currency:'INR':true:'2.0'}}</span> and then before submitting the form you can set the TotalAmount variable

Comment: I want to pass that value to my db so first i have to take that data

Comment: I am taking cartTotal from db and shipping value will be static value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use Form control together with value attribute. It may or may not work. I don't think that is the correct way to use angular Form Control anyway.

The default value of an input element should be set when you initialize a form control. In your case it's  `TotalAmount:new FormControl('2.0')`. 2.0 is the default value you want to set.

If you would like to apply pipe to your form values, I suggest you do it in component.ts file. Angular pipe can also be used in ts files.